# How to repeat the do while until I get the number I want in php?

Tags: php

I'm doing a "do while" php lesson in "codecademy".
**The objective is to throw the dice until we get 6.**
Here is the code I wrote, it runs but not exactly what I want.

```
<?php
    $nombreJet = 0;
    do {
      $jet = rand(1,6);
      $nombreJet++;
      if($jet){
        echo "<div>$jet</div>";
      };   
    } while ($jet == 6);
?>
```

No matter what I get and how many times, it should always end by 6.
But now I get 3 or 5 2 or 1 4 1 etc without 6 at the end.
How to correct it? Thanks!

Comment: 1) Your if statement is not really useful, since you just check if `$jet` has a truthy value 2) If you want to loop until you get a 6 you should do: `$jet != 6`, because this will be true and loop again as long as it is not 6.

Comment: Uh, you might want to reconsider your while logic, currently you are saying: _Do X while $jet is equal to 6_ Shouldn't it be, _Do X while $jet is NOT equal to 6_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the cycle until you get 6, invert the condition at end.

```
$nombreJet = 0;
do {
  $jet = rand(1,6);
  $nombreJet++;
  if($jet){
    echo "<div>$jet</div>";
  };
} while ($jet != 6);
```

Comment: Thank you, your help is useful!

Comment: You are welcome! Anyway, I would prefer the syntax "while (condition) {}", cause it's easy for me evaluate a condition being true instead of false, like in the "do - while" statement.

Comment: this is a tutorial question `codecademy`, so the user need to complete the problem using the `do...while` loop.

Comment: Yes, codecademy is a great website to learn by yourself, I love it! And thanks for all you guys helping me here!

Answer (score 2):

For ending your result with 6,You need to change your while condition.

```
 <?php
$nombreJet = 0;
    do {
      $jet = rand(1,6);
      $nombreJet++;
      if($jet){
        echo "<div>$jet</div>";
      };   
    } while ($jet != 6);
?>
```

Comment: I want to thank you too, your help is useful, too! just one thing that I don't understand, in "do while", is the condition "while" for stopping the loop "do"? So since I want to stop the loop when I get 6, so I say "when you get 6, stop the loop" by adding $jet == 6 for "while", why is it the opposite?

Comment: do while loop is a control flow statement that executes a block of code at least once, and then repeatedly executes the block, or not, depending on a given boolean condition at the end of the block.

Comment: So while ($jet !== 6) means, if we get 1 2 3 4 5, then it's true, repeat the loop, but if we get 6, it's false, then stop the loop, which means what's inside the () of "while", if it's true then repeat, if not, stop! Am I right if I think like this?

Comment: yes you are right,but  in do while condition is checked in last,thats why it will echo 6 and will get out of loop

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! Wish you have a nice day!